# When I define 'neverForLocation' in BLUETOOTH_SCAN permissions, My beacon cannot be found

Tags: android

I don't want to use location permissions when I use the bluetooth scan.

```xml
<!-- Location Permission -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

so, I define the BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission like this:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
     android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"
     tools:targetApi="s" />
```

After then bluetooth scanning function is working, However, my beacon can't be found.

The Google Developer Page said like this.
(https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/bt-permissions)

```
Note: If you include neverForLocation in your android:usesPermissionFlags, some BLE beacons are filtered from the scan results.
```

I really don't know about that means what kind of bluetooth device filtered when using 'neverForLocation'

And, I want to find my beacon's uuid without location permission.
How to solve it?

It works properly request location permissions.
I don't want to use location permission after Android 12.